# How to do alignment on kendo toolbar?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have two buttons,How i can make alignment right and left based on below code Add entity is left and excel export is right.

CONFIG.JS

```
toolbar: [
        {
            template: kendo.template('<a  href="" class=\'k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add\' ng-click=\'addNewRole();\'><span class=\'k-icon k-add\'></span>Add Entity</a>')
        },
        {"name":"excel"}
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

I play around little bit and got the soultion.I added excel button into template and it worked.

```
template: '<button class="k-button k-grid-excel pull-right">Export to Excel</button>'
```